# Are there non-Newton-based theories that explain the world at least as good? If not, why?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, special-relativity, theory-of-everything

The history of physics basically goes like this:
There was one clever guy, Newton, who did some amazing work explaining the motion of objects using mathematics. Over the time the experiments got better and people discovered effects that were not explainable by Newton mechanics (or the generalized Lagrangian mechanics, which put Newton's work on even better mathematical ground, but it's still just Newton in a "renamed" way).

Like relativity, which was introduced by exchanging Galilean by Lorentz transformation, and lead to formulas that still transform to Newton-style for $v \ll c$ (no surprise, because the formulas were developed from taking Newton's as a start, so of course they will have this behaviour).

Or quantum mechanics. Which was introduced by taking Lagrange mechanics (fancy-formulated Newton), rewriting them even further to Hamilton equations and replacing the energies by operators and making the assumption that things are quantized. The limit $\hbar \to 0$ leads back to Newton (no real surprise, again, the equations were *chosen* to behave this way).

I always found this confusing. Why should a better theory lead back to Newton-equations *by design*? Obviously Newton was "wrong" if it only works for slow speeds on medium size scale (it fails for tiny particles, it fails for galaxies and it fails for high velocities). Newton mechanics are easy, yes, but still "wrong". Of course, hypthetical new formulas must explain the movement for slow velocities in mid scale length scales also correctly, yes, but it must not neccessarily be "Newton-style" formulas.

For exmaple, take the approaches made for dark matter. The common approaches try to explain it by new particles that do "not" (or not much) interact (only by gravity), but use the originally-on-Newton-based formulas from general relativity and QM (formulas which were *chosen by design* to contain the Newton-limit, but we know the Newton limit is "wrong").

So, wouldn't it be also valid trying to reformulate mechanics to *first* explain the big scale galaxy movement with totally different geometrical formulas that then still work in small-scale, but without starting from Newton in the first place ("from scratch"), and then arrive at totally new mechanics that explain movements at all scale and speeds without having the explicit Newton-equations or relativity-euqations as a "limit"? Maybe even by using totally different terms or only some of the old terms (i.e. no "mass", no "momentum", no "force", no "energy")?

Are there people working on such approaches, and if so, are they (partly) successful? What are the approaches? If nobody works on such approaches, are there reasons why not?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood how general relativity was developed.  It does not start with Newtonian models and try to improve them.  It starts from a fundamentally differenmt geometrical approach and then *verifies* that you can recover Newtonian physics from GR for given limits.  If a theory could not do that then it would be considered flawed as we know Newtonian physics is accurate enough in those limits.

Answer (score 4):

> Why should a better theory lead back to Newton-equations by design?

A better theory must lead back to Newton’s equations by design because Newton’s laws have centuries worth of experimental confirmation. In the domains where Newton’s laws have been confirmed any alternative theory must match it. Otherwise the existing evidence would contradict the new theory.

> Obviously Newton was "wrong" if it only works for slow speeds on medium size scale

This idea, of theories being “right” or “wrong” was largely popularized by a philosopher named Popper. Frankly, it is a rather poor approach. While Popper’s concept of falsification is important, it ignores verification which is also important.

A more modern approach to science is described using the concept of a domain of validity. The domain of validity describes the physical scenarios where a theory has been confirmed to match experiment. When an experiment comes along that shows some limit where the theory fails, then that physical scenario is outside the theory’s domain of validity. Popper would consider such an experiment to “falsify” the theory, but really such data does not magically erase all of the previous experiments showing the validity of the theory in other domains.

> Of course, hypthetical new formulas must explain the movement for slow velocities in mid scale length scales also correctly, yes, but it must not neccessarily be "Newton-style" formulas.

Notice that in describing Newtonian mechanics you yourself correctly included both force-based analysis and Lagrangian-based mechanics. You correctly stated “it's still just Newton in a ‘renamed’ way”. Similarly, any new formulas that made the same predictions would be just another “renamed” way. We call these reformulations.

One of my favorite such reformulations is Newton-Cartan gravity which reformulates Newtonian gravity in terms of a Newtonian curved spacetime geometry. This is still Newtonian gravity, even though it uses a mathematical framework similar to general relativity.

Comment: "A better theory must lead back to Newton’s equations by design" - why? Consider this: drop some high-res measurement devices in a pre-modern civilisation. They find out how to use them. They see the distant sky. They see galaxy rotation (which we explain by dark matter). They have one person that is super-smart who starts developing a theory that explains this motion. So, you claim that this theory "must" be a theory that in some limit gives Newton's laws of motion in the exact way we know it?

Comment: @FooBar I already explained why. If they don’t lead back to Newton’s equations then they will be experimentally falsified in the domain where Newton’s equations have been experimentally verified. If in your counterfactual history the super smart guy produces a theory that does not reduce to Newton’s laws in the solar system then when they try to apply those laws to the solar system the smart guy theory will be falsified

Comment: Popper was more sophisticated than that. His notion of verisimilitude in e.g. _Objective Knowledge: An Evolutionary Approach_ gives theories more nuanced characterisations than right or wrong. In _The Logic of Scientific Discovery_, he distinguishes verification from corroboration; you might call the latter verification, but he conceded it's an important part of science. He also said we should only reject an old theory when we have a new theory characterizing a specific pattern of contradicting evidence, a _falsifying hypothesis_. This is closely related to the idea of a regime of validity.

Answer (score 1):

Theories that predict reality predict the same reality,  and models that output identical predictions given identical initial conditions must converge to being identical mathematical structures within the domain of agreement. You can push the pattern back way past Newton. Given adequate data to duplicate the initial conditions in Newton's more nuanced theory, Newtonian mechanics converge to Ptolemeic cosmological models for predicting the time and duration of eclipses that were almost 2000 years old when Newton was writing - and which, since they are mathematically easy and predict reality within their domain of relevance, are still useful today.